# How to enable artifact links to Artifactory in the Project Overview table in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

In the Project Overview page in TeamCity there is an "*artifacts*" column that links to the project's artifacts as defined in the *General Settings* page. This allows declaring artifacts that are part of the project's *Build Checkout Directory* See [TeamCity docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings).

In projects that publish to Artifactory, I would like TeamCity to link directly to the artifact in Artifactory.

How can I have Team City show the link to the artifact from Artifactory (rather 
than in the internal repository) in the Project Overview table. See [screenshot from project overview table[image: screen shot from project overview table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zHwd.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to declare an HTML page as the project's artifact. The HTML page should contain a redirection META tag that will point to the artifact in Artifactory. During the build the redirection URL should be updated with the exact path of the artifact.

For example the HTML file would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
      content="0; url=http://myorg.artifactory.com/artifactory/mypproject/@@VERSION@@/pmyproject@@VERSION@@.rpm">
</head>
<body>
<p>My Project @@VERSION@@ RPM will download soon. It is possible to <a href="http://myorg.artifactory.com/artifactory/mypproject/@@VERSION@@/pmyproject@@VERSION@@.rpm">download manually</a>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and during the build the @@VERSION@@ placeholder will be replaced using `sed` or if a build tool such as Ant/Maven is used, using the tool's token filtering feature.